# loading libsvm text file in scikit

Tags: scipy, ipython, scikit-learn, libsvm, jupyter-notebook

I have a text file called "test.txt" which contains data in libsvm format.
Data in this file is represented as follows:

```
165475 0:246870 1124384:2 342593:7 1141651:1 297582:1 1186846:1 17725:1 656602:1 
463304:1 766612:1 573309:1 290046:1 748198:1 216665:1 950594:2 909004:1 29008:1      
105623:1 5018:5 806027:1 1125729:1 757846:1 1023921:2 612980:1 120767:1 51340:1 
108172:5 674420:2
```

where 1st term represents the label and remaining represents the feature and its weight(separated by : ).This is a very huge file(with every label having lots of features and weights).

I am using scikit with ipython notebook and want to load this data in notebook to start processing it.

Can someone tell how to do that.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`load_svmlight_file`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file.html) from `sklearn.datasets`.

Comment: i tried this API                   x_learn,y_train=load_svmlight_file("/Users/riteshk/Desktop/project/sampletrain.rtf")      but it throws ValueError: could not convert string to float: {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1187\cocoasubrtf400

Comment: @riteshk Looks like you stored that file in RTF format rather than text.

Comment: okk..i tried with "TXT" format. Now it gives ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack...                                       However if I reduce the size of feature vector(i.e total number of features for every sample),It works fine.Can u please help me how to resolve this issue??

Comment: @riteshk Edit the full error message into the question, please. I'm not a psychic.